# Javascript timeout function value not incrementing

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I am trying to implement the javascript timeout function using `setInterval` function, when i am using the function, I am able to display the time, the timer is decrementing  but every time i have to reload the page for each iteration.

timer.html

```js
function countTimer(countDownDate) {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is over, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }

}

var countDownDate = new Date("Mar 12, 2017 15:37:25").getTime();

var x = countTimer(countDownDate)

var y = setInterval(x, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

output:

> 2d 2h 45m 37s

Any help would be appreciated ... :) Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) properly, it accepts *string literal code* or function to be executed after the set delay.

Right now you passing *undefined* to it. Change your code as

```
var y = setInterval(function () {
    var countDownDate = new Date("Mar 12, 2017 15:37:25").getTime();
    var x = countTimer(countDownDate)
}, 1000);
```

```js
function countTimer(countDownDate) {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is over, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }

}

var y = setInterval(function() {
  var countDownDate = new Date("Mar 12, 2017 15:37:25").getTime();
  var x = countTimer(countDownDate)
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: In the below code , how do i pass a id as parameter for countTimer function so that it takes the id values....